# Make webpage load before executing another if-then statement VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, html

I'm trying to make a program in Visual Basic that logs you into YouTube and does some other things once you're logged in. Sometimes my program will take you to a page that looks like this, but sometimes it wont: http://puu.sh/9pCua/6320beccef.png so I check to see if the ID for "sign in with a different account" is present. This is the code for that:

```
    If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-link") IsNot Nothing Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-link").InvokeMember("click")
    End If
```

Then it takes you to this page:http://puu.sh/9pCZB/4d1768cf06.png And It'll check to see if the ID for "add account" is present. This is the code for that:

```
    If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-add-account") IsNot Nothing Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-add-account").InvokeMember("click")
    End If
```

After both those links have been clicked it will take you to the destination page where I can enter in the information to sign in. This is the full code for the sub so far:

```
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-link") IsNot Nothing Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-link").InvokeMember("click")
    End If

    If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-add-account") IsNot Nothing Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account-chooser-add-account").InvokeMember("click")
    End If

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

The problem with this is after it clicks on one link the second link cannot be clicked because it doesn't recognize the ID for "add account" because the second webpage needs to be loaded. I could always just hit the button twice but I would like to make it where the second webpage is loaded before executing the second "If Then" statement. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser`, which indicates that a page has loaded.  If you're loading multiple documents then you'll need some logic in the event handler to determine which document is loaded and therefore what to do with it.  You can check the URL of the current document or use some other mechanism.

Comment: Could you give me an example of "DocumentCompleted" that I could use? @jmcilhinney

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples you found when you looked for yourself?

Comment: Yes I didn't understand what you were saying but,after doing further research, now I do thank you. My problem still is adding logic to do document completed part to load more than 1 webpage with 1 click of the button.

Comment: What would that logic be? @jmcilhinney

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can check the current URL and decide what to do based on that. Alternatively, you could just increment a counter each time a new page loads and use that to decide what to do. Pretty common sense stuff; exactly what you'd do if this was a completely physical process. Don't just turn off common sense because you're writing code. Logic still works the same way.